# How to make a simple GUI in python without using any tools such as Tkinter, Eclipse etc?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm making an app using python. I want a very simple user interface just to read a query. It should contain a text box where to type the query and a submit button. Can I make such an interface without using any drag and drop softwares, i.e just by using the code?

Comment: How does Eclipse belong to that list?

Comment: What does "just by using the code" mean?  Libraries like Tkinter are just things you use in your code.

Comment: Of course you can, given you have the time to implement some of the stuff that other people have developed over many years with a lot of effort. I assume you dont want to use any graphics libraries either. So most likely, i'm assuming like a year minimum if you are a genius learner.

Comment: As @BrenBarn said, you can code the GUI without using any graphical design tools, but you still are using f.ex. Tkinter library.

Comment: @xcorat: you can try to write directly to [`/dev/fb0` on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33605/1321) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well simply you can't do that with pure python

BTW start with `Tkinter` as  its more easy to learn than any other gui framework

Your expected code would look like in Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

def submit():
    print "entered text were " + entry.get()

entry = Tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
button = Tk.Button(root,text='submit',command=submit)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

By the way Tkinter is open source so feel free to look how the module is made

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is even possible with pure Python.  You would have to tap into Tcl, a C-like language, or something similar.

Comment: @iCodez I too agree this cannot be done with pure python unfortunately The OP just [changed the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587886/how-to-make-a-simple-gui-in-python-without-using-any-tools-such-as-tkinter-eclip/20587968?noredirect=1#comment30800649_20587904)

Comment: @K DawG sorry, i cannot upvote it since i doesn't have enough reputation :( ,I'm a starter here

Comment: @SoorajChandran: There's a module called [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) that simplifies using `tkinter` and reading its source code is a good way to learn how to use the latter directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't really anything to say other than: no, you can't.

Unlike some other languages, Python cannot do too much without importing modules/libraries.

Meaning, to make a user-interface of any kind, you must first import a GUI development library such as [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/), etc.

Comment: I know we have to import the package , I was asking whether we can do it without using a drag n drop kind of software?

Comment: @SoorajChandran - If I understand you right, then yes.  In fact, that is exactly what Tkinter and wxPython do.  They start with a blank window and then you code in widgets, menus, etc.

Comment: @SoorajChandran  You might want to make that clear in the original question then.

Comment: @iCodez: I think it's quite inaccurate to say that Python "can't do too much out the box".  Many libraries for doing useful things (including Tkinter for GUIs) come with Python, so they are "in the box".  The fact that you have to type "import Tkinter" doesn't mean it doesn't work "out of the box".

Comment: @BrenBarn - Sorry.  I should have been clearer.  I was using the phrase "out of the box" to mean "no importing".